# parallelizable sphere product closed disk

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

From Wall's *Surgery on Compact Manifolds*, P9:

> Observe that $S^r \times  D^{m−r}$ is parallelisable.

If $m > r$, this is true, because spheres can be embedded in Euclidean space of one dimension higher, so $S^r \times  D^{\ge1}$ immerses into Euclidean space of the same dimension. Then the pullback of the (trivial) tangent bundle of Euclidean space gives a trivial tangent bundle of $S^r \times  D^{\ge1}$.

But what if $m = r$? Then let $r = 2$ as an example, we get $S^2 \times D^0 = S^2$, which is not parallelizable.

Is Wall's statement wrong, or am I misunderstanding something about tangent bundles?

Comment: It looks like $2r<m$ might be an assumption for the whole chapter. You're right that this statement is true for $r<m$ but not always for $r=m$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks. Orlik's *Seminar notes on simply connected surgery* has the same claim and also fails to note anything about dimensions. But Orlik's notes seem to be copied from Wall so no surprises here.

Comment: Anthony is correct about the assumption. Good luck with that book, it's not an easy read.